# What does mean "passing" and "heading" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I can't understand what the author want to say in the following sentence, using "passing" and "heading", while we know all mentioned actors worked in television. So what is difference between them? In other words, what do mean "passing" and "heading" in the sentence:

> Several ageing stars embarked upon new small-screen careers, with Groucho Marx and Loretta Young **passing** Charlton Heston and James Dean **heading** in the opposite direction.

Comment: Have you looked up 'passing' and 'heading' in a dictionary?

Comment: If you've already checked in a dictionary, please tell us what you found and why it wasn't helpful. Also, you're asking two separate questions here, one about "passing" and one about "heading".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a metaphor. Imagine that there is a road from "big-screen movies" to "small-screen TV".

A movie actor travels along this road if they start taking on roles on TV.  A TV actor travels along the road in the other direction if they start doing movies.

Groucho Marx was a movie actor.  When he became older he "travelled down the road" and did TV.  But at that time, some TV stars like Charlton Heston, were going in the opposite direction (they were *heading* the other way).  They were starting to do movies. As Marx and Heston were on the road at the same time they must have passed by each other.